# if else condition in htaccess for for admin and frontend in open cart?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have `.htaccess` in which i want `301 redirect`.So when I add 301 redirect code in `.htaccess` it works fine but i can not  login to my backend.But if I remove this code it works fine.I just want it to work in frontend but now because of this code my I cannot login into backend.

**Here is the CODE**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

now i want if else condition or something which helps me to solve this error which works only for frontend of my open cart site and admin remains as it is without redirection.

Comment: Please try my previous directives again and restart or use a different browser before rechecking because once the browser has been redirected `[R=301]` permanently to the wrong address and then you go on to alter the wonky rule, your browser will still be redirected to the old address because of a browser thing.. If it's still not working, try to change my line to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/admin/` and recheck the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always preceded all my code with `RewriteEngine On`. These directives tells to proceed to the `RewriteRule` if not an *admin/** area:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code must exclude all the *admin/** and **.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)* URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Anyway, you can still try to redirect all the *non-www* to *www* URLs with this code but **do not forget add some `www.` in your *"config.php"* admin map**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And always clear your browser cache or use a different one before checking because once the browser has been redirected `[R=301]` permanently to the wrong address, if you then go on to alter the wonky rule, your browser will still be redirected to the old address because your browser is still caching it.

Comment: Hey Thanx for help but it is incurring the same issue. admin is also redirecting. i have tried diffrenet browsers and cleared browser cache too. i guess i need to contact opencart community for this. Thank you again.!

Comment: @RushabhShah Can I know your admin URL?

Comment: 5ervent Thanx for help but it didn't worked ..!! still appears the same error i have contacted opencart let's see what they reply.

Comment: @RushabhShah Did you add some `www.` in your *"config.php"* admin map?